# How to use Group By query in Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, model-binding

In my ASP.NET Web Forms application, I use (Model Binding / Entity Framework).

I want to display the result of my Linq Query (group by) in a Gridview, but I can't !!

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="UsersGrid"
        ItemType="myApp.Models.users" DataKeyNames="id"
         SelectMethod="UsersGrid_GetData"
         AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Fonction" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Count" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public IQueryable<users> UsersGrid_GetData()
{
    ModelData db = new ModelData();

    var result = from d in db.users
                 group d by d.Fonction into grouped
                 select new
                 {
                     Fonction = grouped.Key,
                     Count = grouped.Count()
                 };

    return result.AsQueryable();        
}
```

I have this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating object of anonymous type and trying to convert it as Queryable. That is why you are getting this error.

Try this:
Method 1: If you would like to use the users model itself where 'users' have the properties which you needed to bind to grid view.

```
  public IQueryable<users> UsersGrid_GetData()
    {
        ModelData db = new ModelData();

        var result = from d in db.users
                 group d by d.Fonction into grouped
                     select new users
                     {
                         Fonction = grouped.Key,
                         Count = grouped.Count()
                     };

        return result;

    }
```

Method 2: Use a different model 'p'

```
  public IQueryable<p> UsersGrid_GetData()
    {
        ModelData db = new ModelData();

        var result = from d in db.users
                 group d by d.Fonction into grouped
                     select new p
                     {
                         Fonction = grouped.Key,
                         Count = grouped.Count()
                     };

        return result;

    }

    public class p
    {
        public int? Fonction { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

Instead of 'p' give a valid name as per your application . Also make necessary changes in grid view (You may have to change " ItemType="myApp.Models.users").

Answer (score 1):

The result is not an `IQueryable` of your `Model`, it is an `IQueryable` of [`Anonymous Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). So it should be like this (create a new `DTO` class and return it instead):

```
public IQueryable<DTO> UsersGrid_GetData()
{
    ModelData db = new ModelData();
    var result = from d in db.users
                 group d by d.Fonction into grouped
                 select new DTO
                 {
                     Fonction = grouped.Key,
                     Count = grouped.Count()
                 };
    return result.AsQueryable();
}

public class DTO 
{
    public string Fonction { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```